# How can I place div in line?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place div in line but it's not working in bootstrap. Basically, I'm fetching data from a database and I want data to display inline. I think code should be work

```
<?php 
       
            foreach ($our as $key => $page ) {
                
            ?>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3" >

 

<img src="<?="uploads/".$page['image'];?>" width="90px" height="60px" alt='image'>
<p><?php echo $page['content'];?></p>

    

</div>  
</div>  
</div>
     <?php
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: try to override `display: inline !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Div is a block level element. To make it inline use display property

```css
/* the div selector */ {
  display: inline; /* or inline block */
  }
  
/* if you are using inline css then * /

/* <div style="display: inline;">Bla Bla Bal</div>
```

Comment: Please show your updated code so that I can realize what's still wrong!

Comment: This is codeigniter4 everything is right but it should be placed in line

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WhyChoose?</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');?>">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
    body
    {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .col-md-6 p
    {
        letter-spacing: 1px;    
 font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .bg-dark
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
    }
        .social-link
    {
        
        
        font-size: 35px;
        padding: 10px 10px;

    }
    
    .fa-facebook
    {
        color: #16a4fb;
    }
    .fa-twitter
    {
        color: #1b9bf5;
    }
    .fa-youtube
    {
        color: #d41724;
    }
    .fa-instagram
    {
        color: #ed5348;
    }
    .box
    {
        
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #a2a2a2;
    }
    .box:hover
    {
        border: 1px solid #28a745;
    }
    .box p{
        letter-spacing: 1px;    
 font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }

</style>    
</head>
<body>
    <?php if ($table) {
                foreach ($table as $pages ) {
                   
                
            ?>
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h1 class="text-center" style="color: white;"><?php echo $pages['Whychoose'];?>?</h1>   
</div>  
</div>  
</div>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>  

 <?php 
            if ($whychoose) {
                foreach ($whychoose as $pages ) {
                                    
            ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p ><?php echo $pages['Text'];?></p>
<a class="social-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a class="social-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a class="social-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
<a class="social-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> 
</div>  
<div class="col-md-6 " style="margin-top: 30px;">
<img src="<?="uploads/".$pages['Image'];?>" width="500px" height="540px" alt='image'>
</div>
</div>  
</div>

         <?php
    }
    }
    ?> 



<?php 
       
            foreach ($our as $key => $page ) {
                
            ?>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 box text-center" >

 

<img src="<?="uploads/".$page['image'];?>" width="90px" height="60px" alt='image'>
<p style=" "><?php echo $page['content'];?></p>

    

</div>  
</div>  
</div>
     <?php
    }
    
    ?> 







    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js');?>">    
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where have you included the style : display: inline? I can't find it inside this code? Then how come you expect it to work? Define a separate .css file. and define all of your styles there. And also see if margins or paddings is getting in the way while setting display: inline for those divs.